# draw circle in a new layer actionscript?

Tags: actionscript

i do not want to draw a circle on the same layer the background is. So how can i separate background layer and drawing layer?

using graphics.drawCircle to draw circle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create two Sprites or MovieClips within your MovieClip.
2. Apply beginFill, drawCircle, endFill to them.
3. addChild to them relative to their layer

For example :

```
var player:Sprite = new Sprite()
player.graphics.beginFill(0x111111);
player.graphics.drawCircle(0, 0, 20);
player.graphics.endFill();

var background:Sprite = new Sprite()
background.graphics.beginFill(0x111111);
background.graphics.drawCircle(0, 0, 50);
background.graphics.endFill();


addChild(background);
addChild(player);
```